# On closing the Terminal the nohupped shell script (with &) is stopped

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, scripting

I'm developing a simple screenshot spyware which takes screenshot every 5 seconds from start of the script. I want it to run on closing the terminal. Even after nohupping the script along with '&', my script exits on closing the terminal.

**screenshotScriptWOSleep.sh**

```
    #!/bin/bash

    echo "Starting Screenshot Capture Script."
    echo "Process ID: $$"
    directory=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M")
    mkdir ${directory}
    cd ${directory}
    shotName=$(date "+%s")
    while true
    do
            if [ $( date "+%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M" ) != ${directory} ]
            then
                    directory=$(date "

+%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M")
                cd ..
                mkdir ${directory}
                cd ${directory}
        fi
        if [ $(( ${shotName} + 5 )) -eq $(date "+%s" ) ]
        then
                shotName=$(date "+%s" )
                screencapture -x $(date "+%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S" )
        fi
done
```

I ran the script with,
**nohup ./screenshotScriptWOSleep.sh &**

On closing the terminal window, it warns with,
**"Closing this tab will terminate the running processes: bash, date."**

I have read that the **nohup** applies to the child process too, but i'm stuck here. Thanks.

Comment: This might work: `nohup ./screenshotScriptWOSleep.sh >/dev/null 2>&1 &`

Comment: **FOUND!** Hey all, found the issues behind this. nohup doesn't work as expected in mac's terminal. I used **iterm2** to nohup and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Either you're doing something really weird or that's referring to other processes.

```
nohup bash -c 'sleep 500' &
```

Shutdown that terminal; open another one:

```
ps aux | grep sleep
409370294 26120     1   0  2:43AM ??         0:00.01 sleep 500
409370294 26330 26191   0  2:45AM ttys005    0:00.00 grep -i sleep
```

As you can see, sleep is still running.

Comment: I did this without the **sleep** command. I also tried with **sleep** command. But on closing the terminal window the nohupped script along with the subprocess[**date**, **screencapture**, **sleep**] running terminates. I have read that the child process of nohup also ignores **SIGHUP**. Clarify me if i'm wrong.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just ignore that warning, your process is not terminated. verify with

`watch wc -l nohup.out`